# How to create an Explorer, that let's you choose a file or a directory within the same dialog?

Tags: python, tkinter, interface, directory, pyqt

I'm trying to create a user interface that let's you choose **either a file or a directory**.

PyQt for example has two different static methods, that create dialogs where you can select a file or a directory. But it has one static method to select a file and one method to select a directory.

```
path_dir = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, header, path, options)
path_file = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, header, path, options)
```

I'm trying to find a similar static methods that combines these two. So basically a dialog where it doesn't matter if you select a directory or a file (but within the same dialog).

Comment: Do as explained in the answer to the linked post, but use `dialog.setFileMode(dialog.ExistingFile)` (`ExistingFile`, not `ExistingFiles`) if you just want to select single files.